# What is the difference between member val and member this in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, immutability

When I created a class containing a generic, mutable .NET Stack in F# like the example below, that stack ignores anything I push onto it.

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Interp(code: int array) =
    member val PC = 0 with get, set
    member this.stack: Stack<int> = new Stack<int>() 
    member this.Code = code

let interp = Interp([|1;2;3|])
interp.stack.Push(1)
printfn "%A" interp.stack // prints "seq[]" WAT?!
```

Yet if I make the stack mutable via a property:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Interp(code: int array) =
    member val PC = 0 with get, set
    member val stack: Stack<int> = new Stack<int>() with get, set 
    member this.Code = code

let interp = Interp([|1;2;3|])
interp.stack.Push(1)
printfn "%A" interp.stack // prints "seq[1]"
```

Everything magically works like I'd expect.

What on earth is going on here? My understanding of immutability from previous languages (C# mostly) would say that even though the stack in the first example is an immutable member, that immutablity should only go as far the reference (aka I shouldn't be able to reassign Stack itself). I should still be able to push values to/from it. What am I missing, and if trying to mutate that stack is the wrong thing, why doesn't it throw an exception or a compile error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try to compile the first version, and then use e.g. Reflector to decompile it to C#, you'll see that the stack member is defined like this:

```
public class Interp
{
    public Stack<int> stack
    {
        get { return new Stack<int>(); }
    }

    // Other members omitted for clarity...
}
```

As you can see, this is also valid C# code, but obviously not what you want.

The second version cross-compiles to something like this:

```
public class Interp
{
    internal int[] code;
    internal Stack<int> stack@;

    public Interp(int[] code) : this()
    {
        this.code = code;
        this.stack@ = new Stack<int>();
    }

    public Stack<int> stack
    {
        get { return this.stack@; }
        set { this.stack@ = value; }
    }

    // Other members omitted for clarity...
}
```

This seems more like what you'd want a property to do.

Answer (score 2):

A more idiomatic way to do what you want is this:

```
open System.Collections.Generic

type Interp(code: int array) =
    let stack = Stack<int>()
    member val PC = 0 with get, set
    member this.Stack = stack
    member this.Code = code
```

If you don't need to expose the stack externally, omit the next to last line.

Comment: What's not idiomatic about `member val Stack = new Stack<int>() with get, set`?

Comment: @Daniel it is not idiomatic to create a mutable field for a member that is not going to be mutated.

Comment: @Daniel or more to the point, it's generally more idiomatic to prefer immutable types, or at least members, over mutable ones.

Comment: You're using the same type, `Stack<int>`. The only difference is regular vs. auto property syntax. That's why I thought you were suggesting there's something non-idiomatic about auto-properties.

Comment: @Daniel I am referring to the definition of the type Interp, particularly of its member stack, not to the choice of the type `Stack<int>`.  It would be more idiomatic still to make Interp fully immutable and use `int list` instead, but without more context it's hard to explain how that would work.